# Async data property in a Vue3 component

Tags: javascript, promise, vuejs3

i'm tring to assign a json object to 'customers' like this in my vue component:

```
import api from "@/service/api";

export default {

  data() {
      return {
        ...
        customers: this.api().get_customers(),
        ...
    }
  },

  methods: {
      api() {
        return api
      },
      ...
  }
}
```

and here inside my api.js file

```
async get_customers() {
    await DataService.get_all_customers()
        .then(async response => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
},
```

Now this of course doen't work since I get a Promise as a response not a value. Is there a way to make it work the way I presented here.

I would like the api.js file to remain a separate js file so that I can access it from mulitple components.

Comment: Do you really need to call your API method inside the data function or can you use a lifecycle hook like "created"?

Comment: So I need to access this method from multiple components. If I define it within 'created' I will need to copy-paste it into every single one of them.

Comment: You can keep the method definition in your "api.js" file, but I believe that the execution of this method should be in a lifecycle hook

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the issue is related to the asynchronous nature of your get_customers method, which returns a Promise. Try the following solution:

```
import api from "@/service/api";

export default {

  data() {
    return {
      ...
      customers: [], // Initialize as an empty array
      ...
    }
  },

  created() {
    // Call the method to fetch customers when the component is created
    this.fetchCustomers();
  },

  methods: {
    async fetchCustomers() {
      try {
        const response = await this.api().get_customers();
        this.customers = response; // Assign the data to the customers property
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
    api() {
      return api;
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

And in your "api.js" file, make sure to return the Promise directly from the "get_customers" method without any additional .then or .catch:

```
async get_customers() {
  try {
    const response = await DataService.get_all_customers();
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
},
```